# How to update dataframe columns which are dependent on eachother

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a python dataframe which has two new columns called Open_Value and Close Value.

When Open_Flag = 1 then Open_Value should = 1000, otherwise it should be the previous value in Close Value.

However, Close_Value should be Open_Value * Daily_Change, so the two columns are dependent on each other.

The problem is I need Close_Value to be updated before the next value of Open_Value.

This is what I currently have:

```
            Date ticker  Daily_Change  Open_Flag  Open_Value  Close_Value
0     2022-07-01    AMR      0.982223          1        1000   982.222921
1     2022-07-05    AMR      0.900296          0           1     0.900296
2     2022-07-06    AMR      0.962195          0           1     0.962195
3     2022-07-07    AMR      1.078025          0           1     1.078025
4     2022-07-08    AMR      1.007203          0           1     1.007203
```

This is what I want:

```
          Date ticker  Daily_Change  Open_Flag  Open_Value  Close_Value
0     2022-07-01    AMR      0.982223          1        1000   982.222921
1     2022-07-05    AMR      0.900296          0  982.222921   884.291669
2     2022-07-06    AMR      0.962195          0  884.291669   850.861323
3     2022-07-07    AMR      1.078025          0  850.861323   917.250058
4     2022-07-08    AMR      1.007203          0  917.250058   923.857468
```

How can I update these two columns which depend on each other? Do I need to use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is what youre looking for:

```
s = df['Close_Value'].cumprod()
df.assign(Open_Value = df['Open_Value'].where(df['Open_Flag'].eq(1),s.shift()),Close_Value = s)
```

Output:

```
         Date ticker  Daily_Change  Open_Flag   Open_Value  Close_Value
0  2022-07-01    AMR      0.982223          1  1000.000000   982.222921
1  2022-07-05    AMR      0.900296          0   982.222921   884.291367
2  2022-07-06    AMR      0.962195          0   884.291367   850.860732
3  2022-07-07    AMR      1.078025          0   850.860732   917.249140
4  2022-07-08    AMR      1.007203          0   917.249140   923.856086
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the cumprod doesnt work. This is because the close value is dependent upon the open value. When Open_Flag = 1 then Close Value should be Open_Value * Daily_Change.